# Cannot connect to SQL database (hosting from home)

Tags: sql-server, iis, windows-server-2012

I recently installed Windows Server 2012 and IIS because I wanted to host website from home (inside my network).

I was easily able to host simple static site, but now when I want to deploy ASP.NET site which uses a SQL Server database I have problems.

From this tutorial I "published" site from Visual Studio
http: //youtu.be/DQgbOIjWgBs?t=6m

And here is what error I get:

http://i62.tinypic.com/j9uhjt.jpg

I have installed SQL Server Management Studio and attached database to it, in IIS I have set/up database name and server, so I believe that is also ok.

Firewall is disabled (just for now until I get it working).

Here is SQL Server set-up from IIS

http://i61.tinypic.com/ao2r95.jpg

I don't know where the problem is, maybe in permissions? (I can normally view static page, website folder is located in inetpub folder)

Comment: You should post the relevant bits (the connection string to your database, the ASP.NET error messages) directly here, **as text** - not just as image links....

Comment: Right click your project in the Solution Explorer, Go to Properties->Web and look if you have checked Start URL and inserted the path to your index file. E.g if your Index.cshtml is inside index folder(in the Views folder) then the path should look like this: http://localhost:port/index/Index.

Comment: Will do in fufutre.

I started from scratch, so selected to create new a website, and after I enter adress and destination and click test here is what I get
http://oi57.tinypic.com/2vcar9t.jpg

Cannot add text, too long for this comment